# Reapeated result in Sql query

Tags: mysql, sql, database, repeat

I have an sql query to retrieve data of a particular type ...it goes fine except it repeats the result twice..why??

Here's my code:

```
<?PHP  REQUIRE 'attemptsql.php'  ?>
<?php
$query="SELECT DISTINCT person   FROM kid WHERE Subs=0";
$results = mysql_query($query);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)) {

foreach($row as $field) {
    echo  htmlspecialchars($field) ;
}




}
```

Like I said its ok but instead od th result being:

```
Dan
```

I get:

```
DanDan
```

Note:I only have one record named"Dan"

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `foreach` just only use `while`

```
<?PHP  REQUIRE 'attemptsql.php'  ?>
<?php
$query="SELECT DISTINCT person   FROM kid WHERE Subs=0";
$results = mysql_query($query);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)) {
    echo  htmlspecialchars($row["person"]) ;
}
```

Comment: @TItoAmoo No problem glad to help